# Tourists remove stakes from dead vampires for tent pegs

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, vampire

Long shot.  I remember this one silly incident from a children's book where tourists wandered into a spooky crypt and saw skeletons with wooden stakes in their chests.  They collect up the stakes and take them away with them to use as tent pegs.  Of course the skeletons were vampires and later the vampires come back to life and chase after them.

There may have been at least one vampire in the story already, he/she may even have been a friendly vampire, but his/her ancestors (in the crypt) are not so friendly!

Probably UK and probably 1990s, unless it was an old one.